# Techniques for determining the peak of sine wave via ADC

Tags: current-measurement, signal-processing

From the book "Digital Protection for Power Systems" the author presents some algorithms to process a sinusoidal waveform. For example, below there's a fragment taken from the index. He also mentions the Walsh Transforms in another chapter. Although the author proposes the mathematical formulations, there's no sample code. In my case, I'm reading a 60 Hz signal from a CT, and added a DC shift for the ADC. I don't need to calculate RMS, rather the peak value is just OK. Has anyone used any of these methods? The simplest method I think is to sample let's say at 1 kHz, and then find the min and max.

[image]

Comment: How quickly do you need to know the peak value? Can you wait several seconds? How accurate do you need the measurement to be? Can you tolerate 5% error?

Comment: Since it's a protection device, I would like to know the peak value during the first cycle. I find "seconds" too long. Yes, I can tolerate 5%. .

Comment: You can use 960Hz and with 16 samples you can do a DFT to find the fundamental frequency component (and just scale it to find peak).  Depending on what you were really trying to do, there may be gaps in that approach.  If you are just looking at steady state quantities that should suffice

Comment: @Blue_Electronx I'd phase-lock the ADC on the signal and let it track drift. (In fact, I've done exactly that before in software and used the information to automatically adjust the ADC clock itself so that I could guarantee an exact, fixed integer number of ticks between each peak. Cycle to Cycle errors were used with PID to lock in and stay locked over time. Worked shockingly well. I used an MSP430 which provides quite fine control over the clock rates.)

Comment: @jonk Doing some research, is that Lock-in Detection where I need to generate a reference signal?

Comment: @Blue_Electronx No. The reference signal IS the signal you are monitoring. Even a zero-cross detector isn't entirely accurate. It's always got some bias to it. However, there are several techniques (I'm sure other, smarter people could add more than I know about, too) you can use to lock onto a signal where you know substantial information about it, a priori. You can cross-correlate against an internal version of the expected signal, for example, and get a "delay" from that. Or, once you get lock, you can grossly over-sample near where you expect to see cross-over and peak. Or... more ways...

Comment: Good paper [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cda6/9cd635e042c5b77a31e51a184beabd189019.pdf?_ga=2.63422892.2002053683.1587519508-1423800718.1582981705) by Bogdan.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage with the method of sampling and comparing if the new sample is higher than the last one, until I find the max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once oversampling at 1kHz, 'just finding' the min and max sounds good to me, to well within 5%.

Let's do the error analysis. 1kHz is 16x oversampling, which means you'll always have a sample within 2pi/32 = 0.2 radians of the peak. cos(0.2) = 0.98. With random phasing, your 'peak' will be within (+0%, -2%) of the true peak.

That meets your 5% specification. Do you need to do any more work on this?

What's the noise on your signal? If you need to start averaging samples due to high noise, or rejecting sporadic noise peaks, then life gets a lot more interesting. The simplest mitigation to noise is an analogue filter before your ADC. You will already have an anti-alias filter there, but it might be worth tightening it down to just over 60Hz.

If you need to do (or want to do) digital processing, then the fact that your input frequency is tightly controlled should mean you don't need to actively synchronise to the incoming waveform. As you are (reasonably accurately) oversampling 16 times, or better still change to exactly 16x, you could compute the total power of 8 successive samples, one complete half-cycle. That gives you a measure of the RMS signal, with noise events suppressed somewhat. More half-cycles summed, more noise suppression, but then you're waiting longer for a detection.

If you want to do non-linear noise suppression, then you need to start tracking the signal you're sampling, with a software PLL. The possibilities for making this little area of the project a big area are endless. Don't over-design it.